# Excel: Searching for First Sequence of Zeroes in a Long Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of userIDs, then a couple hundred columns of days, in which I have value per day.

Where AI to AAD are my values per day for that userID, I know how to get the first day a user generated value:

`=INDEX($AI$1:$AAD$1, MATCH(INDEX($AI2:$AAD2, MATCH(TRUE, INDEX($AI2:$AAD2<>0,),0)), $AI2:$AAD2, 0))`

Dates are in row 1, then in row 2 I search for the first value that isn't 0.

But now I want to find the first time (if any) that that user had 30 consecutive days with daily value equal to 0.  How do I go about that?  I am now at the point where I'm just confusing myself.

I guess I COULD make a second sheet where each row instead sums 30 consecutive days from the original sheet, then I look for the first zero value in the same way I previously looked for the first non-zero.  But that feels like cheating when it can presumably be done directly in a formula (an array formula?)

Comment: What should it return, if it finds cells with 30 consecutive zeros for the first time in a row of 200 cells (Columns)? The position of the first zero out of those consecutive 30?

Comment: The column number of the final zero is what I would then be working with, though of course the first column in the sequence is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the first date starting 30 zeroes.

```
=INDEX(AI$1:AAD$1, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$643)/(COUNTIF(OFFSET(AI2, 0, ROW($1:$643)-1, 1, 30), 0)=30), 1))
```

You can add *29* to the value returned by the AGGREGATE for the ending date. You will have to format the returned integer (e.g *36528*) as a date.

Comment: Nice, thanks, that works.  I hadn't heard of AGGREGATE before, looks like a nice command to go learn about now.

Comment: Your original formula would be `=INDEX(AI$1:AAD$1, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$672)/(AI2:AAD2>0), 1))`